# Default date value to 9999/12/31 in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I want to pre fill by date field value to 9999/12/31. I have tried the below code

HTML

```
<div class="col-md-1">
  <datepicker date-format="yyyy-MM-dd">
      <input
        id="endDate"
        type="date"
        class="form-control"
        ng-model="entity.endDate"
        placeholder="yyyy-MM-dd
        ng-required="true"
        ng-disabled="formName == 'VIEWX'"
      >
  </datepicker>
</div>
```

Controller

```
$scope.entity = {
  endDate: new Date(9998, 12, 31)
};
```

I get the prefilled value as '10000-01-31'

Comment: Why? What could be a good use-case for this behavior? Unless your goal is to annoy your users, don't do this. If the user needs to fill in a date close to the current date, prefill the current date, in all other cases, leave it wide open.

Comment: This is a strange behaviour of code. I dont know why it was given a down vote. Pjetr - I dont know for some reason the user likes it that way.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript dates can be dumb.  The Date object uses **0-indexed months**.  From the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Several_ways_to_create_a_Date_object) (emphasis mine):

> Note: Where Date is called as a constructor with more than one argument, if values are greater than their logical range (e.g. 13 is provided as the month value or 70 for the minute value), the adjacent value will be adjusted. E.g. new Date(2013, 13, 1) is equivalent to new Date(2014, 1, 1), both create a date for 2014-02-01 **(note that the month is 0-based)**.

This is further supported by the [`Date.getMonths()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth) method which mentions

> The `getMonth()` method returns the month in the specified date according to local time, as a zero-based value (where zero indicates the first month of the year).

The correct date for December 31, 9999 is

```
new Date(9999, 11, 31);
```

[Plnkr demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/ELKegOP9boM89sW2li6G?p=preview)